# trying to change the font of this link

Tags: css, css-selectors

trying to change the font of this link

```
<a class="navbar-brand text-uppercase" id="TopBrand" href="#Console"> Console System</a>
```

Whats the proper css for this?

???

```
a:link#TopBrand{
    font-family: 'Revalia';
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: If you just want to target that one and only link then just do `#TopBrand {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below solution which you've provided does work. However, there are also other options with which you can take.

```
a:link#TopBrand{
    font-family: 'Revalia';
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

**Example:**

you could use the declared `id` of `TopBrand` to target that specific anchor ( `a` ) element like so:

```
#TopBrand{
    font-family: 'Revalia';
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

or if you want to apply the CSS rules to all anchor ( `a` ) elements then use this:

```
a{
    font-family: 'Revalia';
    font-size: 12px;
 }
```

**EDIT**

> My problem was the position I had it in the  link. OK so using
>   google fonts does it belong at the bottom or the top of my head links?
>   Before or after Bootstrap css and or my own custom css? I've seen
>   examples both ways!

Typically, placing it at the bottom of the head element should do the job.

Comment: what makes you think `a:link#TopBrand{` will not work?

Comment: Thanks, I had that but wanted to confirm it. My problem was the position I had it in the <head> link. OK so using google fonts does it belong at the bottom or the top of my head links? Before or after Bootstrap css and or my own custom css? I've seen examples both ways!

Comment: @NishanthMatha i didn't say that was not going to work, I've just provided an alternative solution.

Comment: I placed it a the very bottom of the <head>

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw the problem wasn't with CSS. It was where he was including his font family. So, It's irrelavent to suggest an alternative in this case

Comment: @JimmyBellmon of course linking your custom CSS last doesn't always mean that it will override the bootstrap CSS as sometimes it goes down to which is more specific, However, in most cases if you link to your custom CSS last it should override the ones that have been linked first.

Comment: @JimmyBellmon you're welcome , if you feel the solution has helped. don't forget to accept answer. :).

Comment: sorry in my initial question I was not sure what the problem was. Thought I was just having some brain cramps and needed different eyes on it!

Comment: @NishanthMatha OPs question didn't clearly explain it as you did now. I simply, answered what was asked.